# Logcat AndroidStudio: D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed*. Предположительно утечка памяти

Tags: android, while, утечка-памяти, сборщик-мусора

Решил добить старый код, исправил вроде бы старые баги, и код должен теоретически выдать нужный результат...
Но в итоге натолкнулся на утечку памяти (так предполагаю ибо пока другого варианта не вижу).

Пытался:
-Убирать статические переменные,
-Обнулял переменные которые не требовались в циклах в дальнейшем,
-Все переменные которые мог - сделал локальными,
-Пробовал ставить задержку в цикле,
-Вопросы на SO в основном по частным случаям.

Ситуация не поменялась :(

Вот сам код:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    int maxNumNew;

    private int dividerNumMax;

    private long biggestPalindrom;


    private TextView tv2;
    private TextView tv3;
    private TextView tv4;
    private int firstPrimeNumPal;
    private int secondPrimeNumPal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);

        biggestPalindrom = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        multipleOfPrime();

    }

    private void findNextPrimeNum(int previousNum) {
        int i;
        int j;
        int z;
        maxNumNew = previousNum;

        findDividerNumMax(previousNum);

        for (i = previousNum; i >= 10000; i = i - 2) {
            if (maxNumNew != previousNum && maxNumNew > 10000) {
                break;
            }
            for (j = 3; j <= dividerNumMax; j++) {

                z = i % j;

                if (z == 0 && j < dividerNumMax) {
                    break;

                } else if (z != 0 && j >= dividerNumMax) {
                    maxNumNew = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void multipleOfPrime() {
        boolean isNotMaxPalind = true;
        int firstPrimeNum = 99999;
        int secondPrimeNum = 99999;

        while (isNotMaxPalind) {

            if (secondPrimeNum < firstPrimeNum && secondPrimeNum > 10000) {
                findNextPrimeNum(secondPrimeNum);
                secondPrimeNum = maxNumNew;
                findPalindrome(firstPrimeNum, secondPrimeNum);
                secondPrimeNum = secondPrimeNum - 2;

            } else if (secondPrimeNum < firstPrimeNum && secondPrimeNum <= 10000) {
                secondPrimeNum = firstPrimeNum;

            } else if (firstPrimeNum == secondPrimeNum && secondPrimeNum > 10000) {
                findNextPrimeNum(secondPrimeNum);
                firstPrimeNum = maxNumNew;
                secondPrimeNum = maxNumNew;
                findPalindrome(firstPrimeNum, secondPrimeNum);
                secondPrimeNum = maxNumNew - 2;

            } else if (firstPrimeNum <= 10000) {
                isNotMaxPalind = false;
                fillLayout();

            }
        }
    }

    public void findDividerNumMax(long maxNumPreD) {

        dividerNumMax = (int) Math.sqrt(maxNumPreD);
    }

    private void findPalindrome(int firstPrimePal, int secondPrimePal) {

        long resultOfMath = (long) firstPrimePal * (long) secondPrimePal;

        String ltrResult = Long.toString(resultOfMath);
        String rtlResult = new StringBuilder(ltrResult).reverse().toString();

        if (ltrResult.equals(rtlResult) && resultOfMath > biggestPalindrom) {
            biggestPalindrom = resultOfMath;
            firstPrimeNumPal = firstPrimePal;
            secondPrimeNumPal = secondPrimePal;
        }

        ltrResult = null;
        rtlResult = null;
        resultOfMath = 0;
    }

    public void fillLayout() {
        tv2.setText("1-st primary number: " + firstPrimeNumPal);
        tv3.setText("2-nd primary number: " + secondPrimeNumPal);
        tv4.setText("1-st * 2-nd = " + biggestPalindrom);
    }
}
```

---

При запуске в Genymotion начало:

```
12-19 22:02:06.185 1137-1137/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-19 22:02:06.461 1137-1137/devtolife.palindrom I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onPointerCaptureChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPointerCaptureChanged
```

---

//Обрезал начало строк типа: `12-19 22:02:06.461 1137-1137/devtolife.palindrom`

```
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15988: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onPointerCaptureChanged (Z)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15990: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15992: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15996: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 704: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 726: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 485: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getCodeCacheDir
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 491: Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 492: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 493: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDataDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDataDir
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 495: Landroid/content/Context;.getDataDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 496: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getExternalCacheDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 498: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalCacheDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 500: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalFilesDirs (Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 503: Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getObbDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getObbDirs
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 505: Landroid/content/Context;.getObbDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 516: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.startForegroundService, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 531: Landroid/content/Context;.startForegroundService (Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/content/ComponentName;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper.createConfigurationContext, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12005: Landroid/support/v7/view/ContextThemeWrapper;.createConfigurationContext (Landroid/content/res/Configuration;)Landroid/content/Context;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0019
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16457: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15889: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 493: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ImageButton.setImageIcon, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.setImageIcon
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16480: Landroid/widget/ImageButton;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 667: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 669: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
```

---

Далее красная строка...

```
12-19 22:02:06.605 1137-1137/devtolife.palindrom E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

---

Продолжение:

```
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 193 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16776: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16777: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMinTextSize ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16778: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16779: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes ()[I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextType
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16780: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextType ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfigurati
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16823: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration (IIII)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16824: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes ([II)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16825: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16778: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0197
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.obtain, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.createStaticLayoutForMeasuring
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 15266: Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;.obtain (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;IILandroid/text/TextPaint;I)Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.isInLayout, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.setRawTextSize
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16815: Landroid/widget/TextView;.isInLayout ()Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0021
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Button.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16336: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Button.getAutoSizeMinTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.getAutoSizeMinTextSize
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16337: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAutoSizeMinTextSize ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Button.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.getAutoSizeStepGranularity
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16338: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Button.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16339: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes ()[I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Button.getAutoSizeTextType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.getAutoSizeTextType
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16340: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAutoSizeTextType ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 222K, 9% free 7391K/8071K, paused 15ms+12ms, total 40ms
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Button.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16346: Landroid/widget/Button;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration (IIII)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Button.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16347: Landroid/widget/Button;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes ([II)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Button.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16348: Landroid/widget/Button;.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.getLayoutDirection, referenced from method android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompat.getLayoutDirection
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15834: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.getLayoutDirection ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.resolveLayoutDirection, referenced from method android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompat.resolveLayoutDirection
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15838: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.resolveLayoutDirection (I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.setLayoutDirection, referenced from method android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompat.setLayoutDirection
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15839: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.setLayoutDirection (I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.setMarginEnd, referenced from method android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompat.setMarginEnd
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15840: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.setMarginEnd (I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.setMarginStart, referenced from method android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompat.setMarginStart
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15841: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.setMarginStart (I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so



    [ 12-19 22:02:06.861  1137: 1137 D/         ]
          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7978610, tid 1137
E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 3328 bytes, got 2920 
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ImageView.setImageIcon, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageIcon
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16515: Landroid/widget/ImageView;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb792f510): name, size, mSize = 3, 1764, 1764
```

---

А вот то что в `Logcat AndroidStudio`:

```
12-19 22:19:27.449 1137-1141/devtolife.palindrom D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 368K, 11% free 7437K/8263K, paused 12ms+0ms, total 16ms
12-19 22:19:27.489 1137-1141/devtolife.palindrom D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 11% free 7435K/8327K, paused 12ms+0ms, total 14ms
12-19 22:19:27.533 1137-1141/devtolife.palindrom D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 11% free 7434K/8327K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 14ms.........
```

Помогите понять где искать баг.

Comment: почему вы думаеие,что у вас утечка?

Comment: Нигде не вижу утечку, ни в логах, ни в коде...

Comment: @pavlofff куда-то ушло 89% кучи, как то трудно представить что оно ушло под создание активити. GC очищает 11%, а остальное чем то занято. Такой лог идет после срабатывания метода "onClick(View v)".

Comment: @Barmaley Хотел изначально весь лог выложить, но матюкнулось что 32222 знаков слишком много для одного вопроса. Потому только 
 с момента срабатывания клика залил в вопрос. Вечером добавлю ту часть лога который идет на создание активити. Возможно там что-то упустил извиду...

Comment: по коду, у вас всё в полнейшем порядке. в нём утечки физически быть не может.

Comment: Пересоздавал проект в андроидстудио заново. - лог тот же. Пробовал также менять версии SDK. Пробовал и на своем смарте запустить - то же самое.